On Positioning Text in a Pspicture with \rput
The following code generates a pspicture which I want to use as the basis for the back cover of a book:
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=5.625in,paperheight=8.49in]{geometry}
%%%  Page size for a 5.5 x 8.25 book.

\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\noindent\begin{pspicture}(-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{white}%
\psframe[fillcolor=red!80!black,fillstyle=solid](-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)%
\psframe[linecolor=red!80!black](-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)% draws frame.

\Huge
\rput[bc](0,20.0){\textcolor{white}{\textbf{A BACK COVER}}}

\large
\rput[tc](0,15.75){\textcolor{white}{\begin{minipage}{4.95in}\lipsum[12]
%\rput[tc](0,15.75){\textcolor{white}{\begin{minipage}{4.95in}\lipsum[12-13]
\end{minipage}}}


\rput[bc](4.25,2.00){\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
    %\psbarcode{0-89555-821-1}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
    \psbarcode{0-89555-821-1}{backgroundcolor=FFFFFF borderleft=15 borderright=15 bordertop=14 borderbottom=10 textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
\end{pspicture}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

and produces the output:

Now, in order to display the text in the manner shown, I have put it within a minipage.
Furthermore, I am interpreting the \rput[tc](0,15.75) command as that which positions the top-center of the minipage at the point (0,15.75).
Hence, I would expect that if I replace \lipsum[12] in the \rput[tc](0,15.75){\textcolor{white}{\begin{minipage}{4.95in}\lipsum[12] by \lipsum[12-13], I will get the additional text appended to the displayed paragraph without any movement of the top of the paragraph.
Alas, this does no happen, for when I run the code with \rput[tc](0,15.75){\textcolor{white}{\begin{minipage}{4.95in}\lipsum[12], I get the following output:

QUESTION: What am I doing wrong? Should I not encase the text in a minipage environment? If that's the case, how is this problem best handled?
Thank you.

I think the c is centring it vertically. Perhaps you want t to align the top of the minipage. If you put a simple X in the same place, you can see what's happening.
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=5.625in,paperheight=8.49in]{geometry}
%%%  Page size for a 5.5 x 8.25 book.

\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\noindent
\begin{pspicture}(-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)%
  \renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{white}%
  \psframe[fillcolor=red!80!black,fillstyle=solid](-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)%
  \psframe[linecolor=red!80!black](-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)% draws frame.
  
  \Huge
  \rput[bc](0,20.0){\textcolor{white}{\textbf{A BACK COVER}}}
  
  \large
  \rput[tc](0,15.75){\textcolor{white}X}% testing only
  \rput[t](0,15.75){%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{4.95in}
      \color{white}
      \lipsum[12-13]
      %         \rput[tc](0,15.75){\textcolor{white}{\begin{minipage}{4.95in}\lipsum[12-13]
    \end{minipage}%
  }
  
  
  \rput[bc](4.25,2.00){%
    \begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
      %\psbarcode{0-89555-821-1}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
      \psbarcode{0-89555-821-1}{backgroundcolor=FFFFFF borderleft=15 borderright=15 bordertop=14 borderbottom=10 textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
    \end{pspicture}%
  }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}


EDIT
Without the X:
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=5.625in,paperheight=8.49in]{geometry}
%%%  Page size for a 5.5 x 8.25 book.

\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\noindent
\begin{pspicture}(-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)%
  \renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{white}%
  \psframe[fillcolor=red!80!black,fillstyle=solid](-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)%
  \psframe[linecolor=red!80!black](-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)% draws frame.
  
  \Huge
  \rput[bc](0,20.0){\textcolor{white}{\textbf{A BACK COVER}}}
  
  \large
  \rput[t](0,15.75){%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{4.95in}
      \color{white}
      \lipsum[12-13]
      %         \rput[tc](0,15.75){\textcolor{white}{\begin{minipage}{4.95in}\lipsum[12-13]
    \end{minipage}%
  }
  
  
  \rput[bc](4.25,2.00){%
    \begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
      %\psbarcode{0-89555-821-1}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
      \psbarcode{0-89555-821-1}{backgroundcolor=FFFFFF borderleft=15 borderright=15 bordertop=14 borderbottom=10 textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
    \end{pspicture}%
  }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}



Thank you for your answer; but when I try removing the "X", the code abends. I would not think such a character is needed. But it seems to be. What can be done to the code to make it not dependent on the X?

@DDS Above I show the output when I remove the X, together with the code I used to produce it. I'm sorry, but I don't know what the code abends means. Could you explain?

Thank you for the edit. Your most recent code works fine for me. (Instead of "abend" earlier, I perhaps should have said "fails to compile").  Thanks again.

@DDS Ah. OK. Yes, 'fails to compile' I understand ;).
